# Fluctuation in Impulse Responses

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I try to set up a basic first differences VAR_Model:

when I plot the IRF it looks like this: [image: Example]

The fluctuation seems suspiciously wrong to me. Of course, the coefficients in my model also change the signs. I've probably misplaced the model or overlooked something.

I did:

1. use Calender and Seasonal adjusted Variables for GDP and Inflation
2. Checked Stationary -> I(1) variables
3. checked the ordering of the variables
4. select Lag length by AIC (7)
5. test for serial correlation -> no serial correlation (p=0.1047)

When I do not use the first differences the IRF´s are looking "smoother":
[image: Example 2]

What could be the explanation for this?
There are signs for cointegration but this shouldn´t be the reason for the fluctiation, should it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the 90% CI for the first diff model, you can see that IRFs are not statistically significant (except for the first few time periods in the bottom IRF plot). Hence, it seems there is no statistically significant response to the impulses modelled and the fluctuations would be some "noise" below statistical significance.

Also, you do not report the number of you observations and data frequency (which should be considered when choosing IRF horizon).

Comment: I have a total of 230 observations, maybe a lag of 7 is a little high. But other lags (e.g. 3) also produce a similar image. 

That the model presented here is not meaningful is clear to me. Nevertheless, I am confused by the fact that the noise does not occur until the difference is formed. I would be interested to know why the noise only occurs when the difference is formed. When it is just white noise why does it disappear?

Comment: I would point out two things here: First, if the VAR model is estimated using non-differenced data (and differencing should be due to non-stationarity), you run into spurious-regression problems. Second, IRFs from VAR with undifferenced series may just appear to lack fluctuations because of the scaling (wide CI). You can try to plot IRFs without the CI.....   Overall - I don't know your data nor your model, yet the "fluctuations" in the differenced VAR model IRFs seem like reflections of noise in the data (of course, I may be wrong here).

Comment: yeah maybe it´s a scaling problem. That is a good reason. I will have a closer look at this. Thank you!